# Change link title with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, hyperlink, anchor

how can I change the text/name(All items)of the first link using JS without adding id/classes.

```
<ul>
<li class="current"><a data-filter="*" href="#">All Items</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-94"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-94" title="View all items filed under Oslavy"> Oslavy</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-93"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-93" title="View all items filed under Svadby">Svadby</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your link that you want to change will **only have its parent "current" as class** **and link being the first child** of the parent you can try following.

```js
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML="Hello";
 }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="current"><a data-filter="*" href="#">All Items</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-94"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-94" title="View all items filed under Oslavy"> Oslavy</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-93"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-93" title="View all items filed under Svadby">Svadby</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the element with `document.querySelector` and then modify it's `title` property directly:

```js
document.querySelector('[data-filter="*"]').title = "Banana";
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="current"><a data-filter="*" href="#">All Items</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-94"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-94" title="View all items filed under Oslavy"> Oslavy</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-93"><a href="#" data-filter=".term-93" title="View all items filed under Svadby">Svadby</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you!! But it didnt work in my case. The second answer was correct for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using jQuery, there are several ways to update the first list item, depending how your HTML was built.

If you are sure the item with the *current* class will always be the first :

```
$('ul li.current a').html('Banana');
```

If you prefer to rely on the order of appearance of your list item, just take the first one:

```
$('ul li:first-child a').html('Apple');
```

**Notice**: Be carefull not to use a too generic selector. There may be unwanted changes on your whole page. In your case, it would be better to have a clearly identifiable parent container and use it to target your list safely.